# Google Play Games manual sign-in seems to create problematic accounts

Tags: android, google-play-games

My attempts to integrate Google Play Games **Sign-In** are mostly working, however there is one oddity:

**If the user does not already have a Play Games account** and declines to sign-in via the automatic sign-in process, **I provide a "sign-in" button that does a manual sign-in.** When they click it in this case, they are seamlessly prompted to create a Google Play Games account. Seems great. It works... they are signed in, they can participate in my leaderboard, everything seems functional...

HOWEVER: **The Google Play Games account that is created by this particular flow seems to (sometimes) be malformed.** If you attempt to view the profile for this player (within the Google Play Games app, using another account), an error is displayed. An example of such a "malformed" Play Games account is:  **LadyAnnie123**

If you try to view that Play Games profile using the Play Games app (please do), you'll see an error message that says "Yikes, there's a problem... It's not you, it's us." (Cute.) The account is set to "Everyone can see your game activity" and "Receive friend invites" is activated.

**[EDIT:] As of 7/31/22, only about HALF of the accounts that I try creating using the flow described above are broken like this. Some of them seem to be perfectly normal.**

Is this even my fault? Can somebody show me an example of a functional manual sign-in button (that doesn't sometimes create disfunctional Play Games accounts in the case where the user's account does not already exist)?

In onCreate():

```
    gamesSignInClient = PlayGames.getGamesSignInClient(this);
    gamesSignInClient.isAuthenticated().addOnCompleteListener(isAuthenticatedTask -> {
        boolean isAuthenticated = (isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful() &&
                        isAuthenticatedTask.getResult().isAuthenticated());
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            signInStatus = true;
            setupLeaderboard();
        } else {
            signInStatus = false;
        }
    });
```

My sign-in button executes signIn() like this:

```
gamesSignInClient.signIn().addOnCompleteListener(isAuthenticatedTask -> {
    boolean isAuthenticated = (isAuthenticatedTask.isSuccessful() &&
                               isAuthenticatedTask.getResult().isAuthenticated());
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        signInStatus = true;
        setupLeaderboard();
    } 
});
```

THANKS!